# Is it possible to show table view cell index path and collection View Index path in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to know that how to show index path both table view and collection view index. In my case table view cell contain many collection view cell. And collection view cell contains one button when user pressed this button an alert show which show the pressed button from table view index (i.e 2) and collection view index (i.e 4).

How do that ?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  
    }
    //MARK:- Tabel View
       
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return 10
       }
       
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CellForTableView
        
        return cell
       }
    //MARK:- Collectio View
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CellForCollectionView
        cell.myIndexPath = indexPath
        cell.TabedDelegate = self
        
        return cell
    }
}
extension ViewController : collectionViewCellTabbedDelegate{
    func clickBtnTabbed(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        print(indexPath)
                   
               let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Show Index Number!", message: "Selected Collection View Index Number is \(indexPath[1])", preferredStyle: .alert)
                       let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                       alert.addAction(okAction)
               
                       self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)  
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Here is my Collection View Cell:

```
import UIKit

protocol collectionViewCellTabbedDelegate {
    func clickBtnTabbed(indexPath: IndexPath)
}


class CellForCollectionView: UICollectionViewCell {
    var myIndexPath : IndexPath!
    var TabedDelegate : collectionViewCellTabbedDelegate?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var clickBtnOut: UIButton!
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
           super.awakeFromNib()
           
           
           self.clickBtnOut.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickBtnAct(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
           
           
       }
     
    @IBAction func clickBtnAct(_ sender: Any) {
        TabedDelegate?.clickBtnTabbed(indexPath: self.myIndexPath)
    }
    
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: @vadian Now Please give me proper solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your realization, but from my point of view I would recommend to use ColletionView instead of TableView because its more flexible. As I understood you have collection view inside table view cell. To get IndexPath you can use delegate to, and after tap on cell you can pass your indexPath via delegate.

If you want to access indexPath of cell inside cell, you can try to access your superview (checkout Stackoverflow) or you can use code below

```
extension UIResponder {
    func next<U: UIResponder>(of type: U.Type = U.self) -> U? {
        return self.next.flatMap({$0 as? U ?? $0.next() })
    }
}

extension UICollectionViewCell {
    var collectionView: UICollectionView? {
        return self.next(of: UICollectionView.self)
    }

    var indexPath: IndexPath? {
        return self.collectionView?.indexPath(for: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

customize these code your own way

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return count
            }
            
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                
                let cell:TypeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! TypeCel 
                cell.CollectVw.dataSource = self
                cell.CollectVw.delegate = self
                cell.CollectVw.tag = indexPath.row
                cell.CollectVw.reloadData()
                return cell
            }
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                let dt = array[collectionView.tag] as! NSArray
                return dt.count
            }
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                
                let cell:collectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! collectionCell
               
                let datGpAry = array[collectionView.tag] as! NSArray
                let dat = datGpAry[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
        cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClk), for: .touchUpInside)
                cell.button.tag = collectionView.tag
                cell.button.accessibilityValue = String(indexPath.row)
                
                return cell
            }
    @objc func btnClk(sender:UIButton) {
            let index = sender.accessibilityValue!
    }
```